# Proof that $\lfloor \log(n) \rfloor = \lfloor \log((n−1)/2) \rfloor + 1$

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have an assignment tomorrow and we should proof that 
$$\lfloor{\log n}\rfloor = \left\lfloor \log\left( \Big\lfloor \frac{n-1}2 \Big\rfloor  \right) \right\rfloor + 1$$
But the floor drives me crazy since I cannot relate to it.
I believe that 
let $m=\lfloor{\log n}\rfloor$ so that $m=\lfloor{\log n}\rfloor$ then $m\le \log n<m+1$ and $2^m\le n<2^{m+1}$ and because $n\in N$ we know that its an interger so $2^m<n+1\le2^{m+1}$ and therefore $m+1=\lfloor \log n \rfloor+1$ but again the $\log(\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$) part kills me.

Would really appreciate some hints since I stuck and can't get forward on my own.

Comment: The equations in the title and the content differ by a pair of $\lfloor\ \rfloor$.

Comment: Is the $\log$ binary, as implied by your work?

Comment: What is $n$? What if $n=1$?

Comment: Pretty sure the inside is the ceil function and not floor. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196363/prove-that-left-lfloor-log-n-right-rfloor-left-lfloor-log-left

Comment: Will it help if you incorporate the $+1$ term into floor and then get it into $\log$ at the RHS...?